# FlexSlider itemWidth not updated on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I need to implement the design in the below image. So, I calculated itemWidth dynamically in the FlexSlider. 
[image]
But it is not updated upon resizing the browser window. Width calculated is correct, but it is not reflected in the actual FlexSlider items. Slider displays correct width only after executing the 'after' function. Is there any possible methods available to refresh the FlexSlider after calculating the itemWidth.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 /* store the slider in a local variable */
  var $window = $(window),
    flexslider = {
      vars: {}
    };

  $('.custom_slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: true,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    directionNav: true,
    itemWidth: getSliderItemWidth(),
    itemMargin: 20,
    customDirectionNav: $(".custom_navigation a"),
    start: function(slider) {
      flexslider = slider;
    },
    after: function(slider) {
      slider.resize();
      /* auto-restart player if paused after action */
      if (!slider.playing) {
        slider.play();
      }
    }
  });

  /* check slider width on resize event */
  $window.resize(function() {
    var sliderItemWidth = getSliderItemWidth();
    flexslider.vars.itemWidth = sliderItemWidth;
  });

  function getSliderItemWidth() {
    var windowWidth = getWidth(),
      desktopSliderWidth = (windowWidth / 2) - 70,
      sliderItemWidth = (windowWidth > 768) ? desktopSliderWidth : windowWidth;
    return sliderItemWidth;
  }

});
```

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/elizabethkmathew/kn0ojsh9/

Comment: Why don't you just let CSS do the scaling for you dynamically?

Comment: How can I show two slides and a portion of the third slide by using CSS?

Comment: With flex. Use auto for first two images and a fixed width with overflow for last. If you make a working snippet with what you have so far, I can have a go at fixing it for you.

Comment: I have updated the question with fiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/elizabethkmathew/kn0ojsh9/

Comment: This already works really nicely. What exactly is the issue with it? Rescales fine for me.

Comment: When I resize the browser window, I have calculated the slider width in order to maintain 3 slides (2 slides + potion of the 3rd slide) on the screen. But in some scenario, that width is not reflected on the slider. It shows 2 slides or one slide and a portion of the second etc.